# z-index and Chrome 26

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, z-index

z-index is not working well with Chrome version 26, as I have 2 divs

```
 <style>
      #div1{
           position:relative;
           z-index:1000;
         }
      #div2{
           position:absolute;
           z-index:10001;
 </style>
```

It works well on Firefox but in Chrome its not.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html

Comment: Can you post the div1 and div2 HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have syntax errors.  You are missing closing curly brackets.

```css
#div1 {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1000;
}
#div2 {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10001;
}
```

[jsfiddle.net/kUmYh](http://jsfiddle.net/kUmYh/)

Comment: sorry ,,for that but In my actual code I didnot miss that ..still have the problem

Comment: @RemonAmin - Please post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the problem.  I don't see it in mine: [jsfiddle.net/kUmYh](http://jsfiddle.net/kUmYh/)

Comment: @RemonAmin - Your updated jsfiddle has a unique URL.  Please share the link to it.

Comment: @RemonAmin - You have an extra curly brace in your jsfiddle.  [When the syntax error is corrected](http://jsfiddle.net/kUmYh/3/), it displays as I expect. Div2 has a higher z-index than Div1 and displays above Div1.

Comment: did you try to start from parent `div` sample: `#parentDiv #div2 {position:absolute; z-index:10001;}`